# Adding custom :new routes using Rails 3 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 2 we can add custom `new` actions to resourceful routes, like:

```
map.resources :users, :new => {:apply => :get}
```

How do we achieve the same thing in Rails 3?

```
resources :users do

  get :apply, :on => :new    # does not work

  new do
    get :apply               # also does not work
  end

end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:path_names` as [explained](http://guides.rails.info/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments) in the edge routing guide:

```
resources :users, :path_names => { :new => "apply" }
```

That will only change the path to `apply`, it will still be routed to the `new` action. I don't think changing that is explicitly supported anymore (which is probably a good thing).

If you want to keep your `apply` action, you should probably do:

```
resources :users, :except => :new do
  collection do
    get :apply
  end
end
```

But it leaves you wondering whether it isn't better to just rename the `apply` action to `new`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
resources :users, :path_names => { :new => 'apply' }
```

Note that if you want to re-map the `new` route to `apply` for all your routes then you can use a scope:

```
scope :path_names => { :new => 'apply' } do
  # The rest of your routes go here...
end
```