# Mapping a subroute/subaction to a controller action in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Lets say we have a **GoodTimes** controller and we want to create the following mappings between routes and controller actions (in addition to the standard resources):

```
/good_times/new/party          {:controller => "good_times", :action => "party"}
/good_times/new/afterparty     {:controller => "good_times", :action => "afterparty"}
/good_times/new/eurorave       {:controller => "good_times", :action => "eurorave"}
```

In Rails 2 land we could do:

```
map.resources :good_times, :new => {:party => :get, :afterparty => :get, :eurorave => :post}
```

Our path-helpers would then be:

```
party_new_good_time_path
afterparty_new_good_time_path
eurorave_new_good_time_path
```

What is the preferred method of accomplishing the same in Rails 3 land?

**This question is answered here: [Adding custom :new routes using Rails 3 routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044531/adding-custom-new-routes-using-rails-3-routing)**

Comment: It doesn't look like the question you pointed out answers this. Can you answer your own question and clarify?